# переделка из процедурного в ООП

Tags: php, ооп

Доброго времени суток, есть скрипт в процедурном стиле, нужно переделать его в ООП, основную часть скрипта уже перевел, осталась эта часть которую никак не получается в класс заключить дабы унаследовать все что в нем есть

```
if(isset($_GET['category'])){
    $id = (int)$_GET['category'];
    // хлебные крошки
    // return true (array not empty) || return false
    $breadcrumbs_array = $this->model->breadcrumbs($categories, $id);

    if($breadcrumbs_array){
        $breadcrumbs = "<a href='/cat/'>Главная</a> / ";
        foreach($breadcrumbs_array as $id => $title){
            $breadcrumbs .= "<a href='?category={$id}'>{$title}</a> / ";
        }
        $breadcrumbs = rtrim($breadcrumbs, " / ");
        $breadcrumbs = preg_replace("#(.+)?<a.+>(.+)</a>$#", "$1$2", $breadcrumbs);
    }else{
        $breadcrumbs = "<a href='/cat/'>Главная</a> / Каталог";
    }

    // ID дочерних категорий
    $ids = $this->model->cats_id($categories, $id);
    $ids = !$ids ? $id : rtrim($ids, ",");

    if($ids) $products = $this->model->get_products($ids);
        else $products = null;
}else{
    $products = $this->model->get_products();
}
```

Comment: Во-первых, здесь явно нужен шаблонизатор. Во-вторых, а зачем здесь ООП?

Comment: прежде чем куда то приписывать ООП решите куда более важную задачу - разделение слоев бизнеслогики приложения и доступа к данным,  и их представления. мешанина их пхп и хтмл это куда большая проблема.

Comment: andreymal, поместить в класс и вызывать через объекты, ведь такой вид в контроллере не очень смотрится

Comment: teran, к чему это все? есть есть класс выводящий многоуровневое меню, осталось данный фрагмент кода(навигационная цепочка) поместить так же в класс для удобства и большей простоты

Comment: к тому что в принципе генерация хтмп чистыми средствами пхп кода это неюзабельная шляпа. используйте шаблоны.

Comment: teran, какие шаблоны у меня скрипт готовый и работает, просто данная запись некрасиво выглядет и засоряет контроллер

Comment: @аноним некрасиво выглядит неправильная архитектура, и ООП здесь ни при чём — хорошие приложения можно делать и без него (или с минимальным его участием). Лучше перепишите на шаблоны